# Debian 7 and PHP 5.4.4 error reporting

Tags: apache-2.2, php.ini

I use default php.ini and then in my PHP script (local.settings.php in Drupal) I simply set ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT');
According to documentation this means "show all messages minus notice and strict warnings". But in my case it still shows strict warnings! I have no idea why, because I clearly stated "~E_STRICT". If I comment it out then I see strict warnings. So it means that default from php.ini "E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT" didn't do its job as it also has "~E_STRICT" but I still see strict warnings.

On Debian 6 there was Suhoshin patch which was controlling usage of php_ini in PHP scripts. Especially when you try to get more memory than defined cap. Now on debian 7 there is no Suhoshin nor any other security element that might control php_ini. 
So what might cause php_ini not to be executed? Is there some new variable / setup / other that needs to be checked?

Comment: If you are seeing the strict warnings being rendered _by Drupal_ within your layout, then [this is a Drupal issue](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/99947/10258). Drupal has customized handling for PHP warnings.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to restart your webserver.  If you've changed the `php.ini`, it is only read at service start.

Type:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I have changed local.settinggs.php in which I added php_ini. php.ini file in php5 folder I didn't touch.